# Kubernetes docker secret to private docker repository with token

Tags: kubernetes

Usually to get image from private repo we use below commands

```
image:
  repository: <repo>
  tag: <version tag>
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
imageCredentials:
  name: <registry_name>_credentials
  registry: <repo>
  username: <username>
  password: <pw>
```

But what if i have another structure of credentials to access my private repo like below. How it need to be put in my kubernetes manifest to get access to my repo?

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://backend.jfrog.io": {
            "auth": "some_token",
            "email": "email@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster (your config file)? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Mykola, I use minikube

Comment: Could you please answer the remaining questions asked by Mykola?